# react-router generatePath() with optional path params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having a path like `to/:param/(optional)?/:optionalParam?` so when I use `generatePath()` like:

```
generatePath('to/:param/(alsoTo)?/:optionalParam?', {
  param: 'abc',
  optionalParam: 'xyz',
});
```

I get something like `to/abc/xyz` instead of `to/abc/alsoTo/xyz` (the former misses `alsoTo` in the path).

What should I do to get `to/abc/alsoTo/xyz` with `/alsoTo/` in the generated path as well?

I'm using react-router v5.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make `alsoTo` a parameter when you pass it to `generatePath`, i.e.

```
generatePath('to/:param/alsoTo/:optionalParam?', {
  param: 'abc',
  optionalParam: 'xyz',
})
```

Of course, if you want to conditionally add `alsoTo`, pass it as a param

```
generatePath('to/:param/:alsoTo(alsoTo)?/:optionalParam?', {
  param: 'abc',
  optionalParam: 'xyz',
  alsoTo: someValueForAlsoTo,
});
```

The value of `alsoTo` in the params object must be `'alsoTo' | undefined`, else you will get an error.